# how to make join query between three tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I want to build a query in laravel between three tables (regions, countries, packages) such that table are related together.

1. regions table contains (id, name, description)
2. countries table contains (id, region_id, name, description)
3. packages table contains (id, county_id, pkg_title, pkg_description, price)

I want to select all packages where region_id=1
how can I make query for this situation in laravel query builder. please help me about this question

Comment: when you show you querybuilder? :)

Comment: Can you please shiw us your code?

Answer (score 1):

Set your models as follows.

```
class Region extends Model
{

}

class Country extends Model
{
    public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
    }
}

class Package extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

And state following query inside your method.

```
$region_id = 1;
$PackageWithRegions = Package::with([
    'country' => function ($county) use ($region_id) {
        return $county->with([
            'region' => function ($region) use ($region_id) {
                return $region->where('id', $region_id);
            }
        ]);
    }
])->get();
// $PackageWithRegions is a collection of packeges with regions where regiion_id = 1
```

More on [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Kindly make the answer as accepted. Glad you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent model relationship to prform this, like below

In region controller file

```
$region = Region::where(['id'=>1])->with(['country'])->get(); ///fetch region with country calls relation declared in region model
```

In Region.php model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Region extends Model {

  protected $table = 'regions';


  public function country(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Country','region_id')->with(['packages']); ///this will fetch country with all pacckages on matching region_id, join of package  with country is declared in country model. 
  }
}
```

In Country.php model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model {

  protected $table = 'countries';

  public function packages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Package','county_id'); //join of country with packages on county_id
  }

}
```

In Package.php model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Package extends Model {

  protected $table = 'packages';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in Laravel doc (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) in section Has Many Through that if you have a model like:

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

Then you can access to last relation in this way:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User');
    }

}
```

Or using customs relations IDs:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

So, you can access to the posts of a country:

```
$posts = Country::get(2)->posts;

// with where:
$posts = Country::where('name', '=', 'USA')->get()->posts;
```